# Create form using smarty function

Tags: php, forms, smarty

Yes! that's the exact doubt I have. I was given an assignment of

```
Create a form using smarty functions 
(fields should be First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, Gender, 
Qualifications, Phone number, etc.)
```

and I don't have any idea what they are talking about. So I want to ask that is there any function() which is used for making form elements or any other possibilities?I tried searching on google but didn't get any positive result.

Comment: Read the [Smarty documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/).

Comment: That i have already done.

Comment: The question is too broad. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yup i made it..

Answer (score 1):

PHP Code

```
<?php
include_once "../prepengine-header.php";

$lets = $_POST['user_lang'][1];
$var = $_POST['user_lang'][0];
$var .= $lets;
$formdata = "";
if (isset($data['submit'])) {
    $formdata .= $data['user_firstname']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_lastname']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_address']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_qual']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_gender']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $var."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_email']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_num']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_select']."\n" ;
}
$theme->assign('data',$data);
$theme->assign('formdata',$formdata);
echo($theme->fetch('smartart/screen5-a (1).tpl'));

?>
```

Smarty code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="container">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form" id="registration_form" method="post" action="#"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="firstname">First Name: <sup style="color: #FF0000;">*</sup></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter firstname" class="form-control" required="required" />
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="lastname">Last Name: <span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname" class="form-control" required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="address">Address <span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <textarea id="address" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Provide Address" required="required"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="gender">Gender <span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <{html_radios name='gender' values=$cust_id output=$cust_gender selected=$custom_id separator='<br />'}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="user_lang">Languages</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <{html_checkboxes name='user_lang' values=$cust_ids output=$cust_names selected=$customer_id separator='<br/>'}>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="user_country">Country</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <{html_options name='select' options=$myOptions class="form-control"}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```